# kendo upload async, how submit with javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, upload, kendo-ui

How submit a **Kendo Upload file** in async mode with a external button using javascript,
it's possible?
someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After initially selecting a file, KendoUpload will create a button you can select with $(".k-upload-selected").   Calling click on this button will POST back to your saveUrl setup in the async  options.  You will need to set autoUpload: false.

On select in kendUpload, you can access the Kendo generated upload button, hide it then trigger the click event in myUploadButton's click.

My original code was inside a Backbone view.  Just to simplify I pulled it out.  I haven’t tested the code below, however it should be fairly close to what you need.

> ```
>         var myUploadButton = $("#save");        
>         var kendoUploadButton;
> ```

```
        $("#files").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: http://uploadurl",
                autoUpload: false,
            },
            multiple: false,
            select: function (e) {

                setTimeout(function () {
                    kendoUploadButton = $(".k-upload-selected");
                    kendoUploadButton.hide();
                }, 1);
            }
        });

        myUploadButton.click(function() {
          if(kendoUploadButton)
              kendoUploadButton.click();
        });
```

[Kendo Forum post on KendoUpload Trigger](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/upload/trigger-and-upload-from-onclick.aspx)